# Is gradient in the tensorflow's graph calculated incorrectly?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, tensorboard

A very simple example in tensorflow: `min (x + 1)^2`  where `x` is a scalar. The code is:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(initial_value=3.0)
add = tf.add(x, 1)
y = tf.square(add)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(y)
```

Then write the graph to disk:

```py
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("some/dir/to/write/events")
writer.add_graph(graph=graph)
```

Finally, visualizing it in tensorboard, it looks like this:

[image]

The question is, why is the "Add" node connected with the gradients? I think since I am trying to minimize y, the "Square" node should be.  Is this a bug?  Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is no bug involved. You just need to understand what is a gradient and know how to compute one yourself. So `(x+1)^2' = 2*(x+1)`. Which means that you do not need to calculate `(x+1)^2` to calculate the gradient. If you will zoom in the gradient part you will see that it calculated the gradient of your square and figured out that it does which part of the graph is needed there :[image]

Here is a more interesting and more intuitive example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(initial_value=3.0)
y = tf.cos(x)

train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(y)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('logs', sess.graph)
    writer.close()
```

You should know that `cos(x)' = - sin(x)`. Which means that only `x` is needed to calculate gradient. And this is what you see in the graph:[image]

Comment: Very cool example! finally I can understand the so-called *symbolic* gradient! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Jie.Zhou yes, I think this is a very good question which sheds light on many important topics: 1) how the graph is constructed, 2) how the gradients are calculated in math and how is it applicable to TF

Comment: Would this allow to get an expression for a gradient / hessian that I am not able to calculate by hand ?