# How dy(upstream gradient in Tensorflow) is getting calculated below?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient

In the below code:

- dy is computed as 1. How is this value getting computed (whats the math)? as per tf.custom_gradient guide, dy is upstream by gradient
- Why final gradients is getting multiplied by clip_norm value(0.6)?
  (It means final_gradients of (v * v) is getting multiplied by 0.6 , gradient of v * v is 2v, why is multiplied by 0.6?)

  ```
   @tf.custom_gradient

   def clip_gradients(y):

     print('y',y)

     def backward(dy):

       print('dy',dy)

       return tf.clip_by_norm(dy, 0.6)
     return y, backward


   v = tf.Variable(3.0)

   with tf.GradientTape() as t:
     output = clip_gradients(v * v)
     print('output',output)

   print('Final Gradient is ',t.gradient(output, v))
  ```

'''

Code output

```
y tf.Tensor(9.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
output tf.Tensor(9.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
dy tf.Tensor(1.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
Final Gradient is  tf.Tensor(3.6000001, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Why final gradients is getting multiplied by clip_norm value(0.6)?` Also, maybe that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44342968/7370153) (although about TF1) could help you understand.

Comment: Edited the question, pls look into it
It means final_gradients of (v * v) is getting multiplied by 0.6 , gradient of v * v is 2v, why is multiplied by 0.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dy` is initialized to `1.` at the beginning of the backpropagation because this is the derivative of the identity function. By applying the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), we know that `f(g(x))'` is `f'(g(x))*g'(x)`. If `f` is the identity function (`f(x) = x`), then the previous expression becomes `1*g'(x)`.

Your function `clip_gradients` clips any value of the gradient over `0.6` to `0.6`. The initial value of `dy` is 1.0 (as explained above).

If we apply the chain rule to your example, we have:

- the derivative of the identity is `1.0`, then clipped to `0.6`.
- the derivative of `v*v` is `2*v`

By applying the chain rule, we get the final gradient to be `0.6*2*v`, which is equal to `3.6` when `v=3`.

Comment: 'dy is initialized to 1. at the beginning of the backpropagation because this is the derivative of the identity function'
Would this statement always hold - whatever function are we giving in model argument?

Comment: Yes. because you can always apply `f(model)` where `f` is the identity function without changing your end result.